# Symfony 2 File Structure for Assets

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating my first project in Symfony 2 and I am a bit confused as to where to store my assets (CSS, JS, images etc...) in each situation.

I am starting to understand how the template system works where you should create your Bundles to be standalone and then override them with site specific content in app/Resources.

But when it comes to assets do I create a "public" folder in app/Resources for site specific content?

And why are some assets for bundles are kept in web/bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place css,images,js and so on into a folder inside the bundle them supposed to belong to.
This folder is called `public` and is contained into `Resources` folder (obviously, inside it, you can make other folder for css, js, ... division).

Once you've done that, you could use (from **C** ommand **L** ine **I** nterface a.k.a. **CLI**) following command:

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

In that way, you're telling symfony2 (this is a default behaviour) to **make a copy** of all folders named `public` contained into `Resources` folder, into `web` folder.
Symfony will create (or extend, if exist) a folder named `bundles` containing all assets of your application (included some assets from vendors).

#### Please pay attention

If you run above command, you're making a copy of your resources so every time you change them, you have to launch again command itself. A better method is to use symlinks changing above command as follows

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

The reason of `web` folder as destination folder is that, your web server (apache or others is the same) should access only resources contained in it and leaves symfony2 the task of rerieve all resources.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome thanks. So if I wanted to override an image in a bundle I would run the console command then update the file in the web/ folder? Also where would you put the assets for the main template of the website "app/Resources/views/base.html.twig"

Comment: @TheoKouzelis: what do you mean with "override" ? You mean change it by replacing file? If it is, follow my advice and use symlink. In that way, you have simply to change this image and all changes will reflects everywhere you use that asset. Second question isn't clear, at least to me: assets are bundles concept, not template concept. If you mean "where would you put TO USE them" I suggesto a main template that will be extended by whole site pages

Comment: Sorry I think I am a bit confused by few of the concepts. I think you have answered my question regarding bundles with the symlinks. But my other question was about where would you put the CSS for the templates that you create in app/Resources

Comment: @TheoKouzelis: Ok, I would put them into bundle where they're used. If you have some bundles, I suppose that one *main* bundle will be present, isn't it? So, put them into this "main" bundle, at the locations showed in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the Symblog tutorial... [Symblog](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/)

[This](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/customising-the-view-more-with-twig.html) part in particular is about assetic

Comment: I have already skim read this tutorial and I couldn't see anything that clearly answered my questions